# Is there a script to change ip address to bypass filtering?

Tags: script, ip, web-filtering

Is there a script to change ip address to bypass internet filtering?

as I know programs like freegate change the ip address to bypass internet firewalls.I want to write a script to do it by myself. can I do that?

Comment: Those other systems do this by using external ips for re-routing. It's usually not easy to change the ip assigned to your modem by your isp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, at least not to obtain the end you seek.

Freegate operates as a proxy. it is not changing your IP address, its just forwarding on your traffic so it looks like the traffic is coming from them, not from you.

This is not something you can do, because you'd be masquerading as yourself, which obiviously won't fool anyone. no scripting on your end will change that. Also note that you cannot really change the IP address that you ISP assigns to you. if you tried, you'd be cut off from the Internet.

So look into proxy, VPS, and VPN services, who will let you appear to be them from an external observers point of view.

Comment: Its not really pretending if you are actually connected to an entirely different network in the case of a VPN.  A proxy on the other hand works entirely different.